# Android Vertical Menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I would like to create a menu to appear on the screen when the Menu button is pressed.I've implemented it and it appears in the bottom of the page but not the one i would like... Hereunder my code and my goal picture to achieve

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.collapseall:
        // Single menu item is selected do something

        collapseAll();

        return true;

    case R.id.expandall:

        expandAll();

        return true;
    }
}
```

My desired Menu:

[image]

My current Menu:

[image]

Edit:

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/expandall"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Expand All"/>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/collapseall"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:title="Collapse All"/>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/myprofile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:title="My Profile"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/signout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Sign Out"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Can you provide menu.xml file also?