# Android Menu when menu button is pressed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextmenu, android-menu

I would like to create a menu to appear on the screen when the Menu button is pressed.  I've implemented it and it appears in the bottom of the page but not where I would like. My code is here with an image of what I am trying to achieve.

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/expandall"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Expand All"/>


<item
    android:id="@+id/collapseall"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="withText"
    android:title="Collapse All"/>


<item
    android:id="@+id/myprofile"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="withText"
    android:title="My Profile"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/signout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Sign Out"/>
```

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.collapseall:
    // Single menu item is selected do something

    collapseAll();

    return true;

case R.id.expandall:

    expandAll();

    return true;
  }
}
```

My desired Menu:

[image]

My Current Menu

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Vertical Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254719/android-vertical-menu)

Comment: You need to be using an `android:Theme.Holo` theme as your underlying app theme, and it looks like you are using an old theme like `android:Theme.Light`

Comment: I am using like : android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Comment: When i try to change it to the android:Theme.Light , My tabs are disappeared and only i can see only 1 tab instead of 4!!! Also the menu is not working at all at this time.

Comment: Now it works when using android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" But my other 3 tabs disappeared!! i don't know why. I'm using a custom view for each tab but it seems it can only show 1 tab filling the parent, Any ideas?

Comment: The weird thing its working fine in the emulator but on the device it is not. only 1 tab appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing android:orderInCategory from all item

Comment: I did try that and no luck, The same thing!

Comment: which device are you using

Comment: I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3 and Eclipse Emulator as well.

Comment: try changing all to android:showAsAction="always". if that doesnt work then you can try using custom action layout android:actionLayout="@layout/layoutname"

Comment: same results for both...I've tried to create a dummy layout including 1 textview and i did it as your instructions but unfortunately it's the same :S

Comment: If you already have a working scenario that i could try from may be i could be wrong it would be much appreciated!

Comment: <item
  android:id="@+id/information"
  android:showAsAction="never"/>
 <item
  android:id="@+id/details"
  android:icon="@drawable/Details"
  android:title="Detail"
  android:showAsAction="never"/>
 <item
  android:id="@+id/search"
  android:icon="@drawable/smallsearch"
  android:title="Search"
  android:showAsAction="never" />
 <item
  android:id="@+id/search"
  android:icon="@drawable/report"
  android:title="Search"
  android:showAsAction="always" />
 <item
  android:id="@+id/aboutMenuItem"
  android:title="@string/about"
  android:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>

Comment: Thanks it's working fine by your code but i have to modify the Theme to @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar in order to work fine :)